# customer's password not displayed in email templates in Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, email-templates, password

After New account registration in 'welcome email' password not visible.
If I want to send a password through email then how to send it.

Is it good practice to send a password in clear text?

Answer (score 0):

There is several discussion on sending a password through email is bad or good practice.

Magento 1.9 version has a problem to send a password in emails. and not set var values under {{htmlescape var=$customer.password}}

**Solution**-Extend AccountController.php from customer module.
you will find one line there

```
$customer->cleanPasswordsValidationData();
```

a comment on the line.

comment in other places too.

also in the customer module in `Customer\Model\Customer.php`
you will find function

```
public function cleanPasswordsValidationData()
{
    $this->setData('password', null);
    $this->setData('password_confirmation', null);
    return $this;
} 

public function cleanPasswordsValidationData()
{
    // $this->setData('password', null);
    $this->setData('password_confirmation', null);
    return $this;
}
```

But one thing should be noted here 
You can get a password in clear text only when the customer creates the account after that you cannot get into text.

Once it is saved in the database and you lose the customer instance you cannot get back the password because it is hashed.

But it is bad practice to send a password in clear text through email.

so you could remove the password label from the email template entirely or change the email template to something like this:

```
Password: The password you used to create your account.
```

I think everyone with this problem will get a solution.

Thank you.